# Prevent environments table and figure to change default colour

Tags: tables, floats, environments

When environment `table` is invoked, everything within it becomes black.  Similarly, the caption of `figure` is also black.  In the MWE below, capital letters and caption are both black:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}

\begin{document}

\color{red}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to prevent those environments to change the colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Move `\color{red}` before `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}

\color{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Floats don't force **black** they force the default document font and color, which for color is the color in force at `\begin{document}`

If needed you can change the default color mid document with

```
\renewcommand\normalcolor{\color{blue}}
```

Comment: Oh, I understand.  This still means I cannot have, say, one half of the document with one default colour and the other half with the other? :(

Comment: @Pygmalion sure just redefine  `\renewcommand\normalcolor{\color{blue}}`

Comment: Would you mind include that into the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @Pygmalion done